# Answers were migrated but not the question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

I was trying to get some stats on migrated posts when I ran into a problem.
I had thought that every migrated answer would belong to a migrated question, but this is not the case.

For example, consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion).  According to all of: its [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/406760/revisions), its [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/406760/timeline), and [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1094827) -- **it shows as never migrated**.

Meanwhile, at least 292 of [that **question's answers do show as migrated.**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1094830)
For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433341):

[Revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/433341/revisions):

> [image: Sample Rev History]

[Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/433341/timeline) (Click for larger image):

> [image: Sample Timeline]

How did these answers come to be migrated (at least for a little bit) but not the parent question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mods can delete migration history. Which, I apparently did on that question, as well as on many - but not all - of the answers.

I have no idea why.

Comment: Re: "I have no idea why."  Then you can put it back?!  The SQL gets nasty the way it is right now (and liable to timeout SEDE).

Comment: Not really, @Brock - but I might be able to help you with that query if you give me a link (or a spec).

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9, that line of inquiry didn't {strike}support my agenda{/strike} yield consistent results and I've dropped it. ...  But I've got plenty of other queries, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331394) that timeout on SO's data; if you can tune something up to make it fully functional, that would be great.